# Ninject InThreadScope() resolves a new class instance despite running on the same thread

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ninject, mediatr

At my job we have an ASP.NET MVC (.NET 4.6.2) system that uses a class called `TenantService` to carry tenant data around. We use Ninject to inject a reference to this class' interface into other classes.

We have a Quartz job which also receives the `ITenantService` injection into it's constructor.
Right at the beginning of the `Execute` method of that job, we provide the tenant ID to the `TenantService`. After that, the job sends a MediatR command.

```
private readonly ITenantService _tenantService;

public SubmitSubmissionJob(ITenantService tenantService)
{
    _tenantService = tenantService;
}

public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext)
{
   (...)

   _tenantService.SetTenant(clientId);

   (...)

   _commandBus.SendCommand(new SubmitApplication(applicationId));

   (...)
}
```

MediatR redirects this command to an aggregate handler, which also receives an injection of the `ITenantService` into it's constructor:

```
private readonly ITenantService _tenantService;

public AggregateCommandHandlerBase(ITenantService tenantService)
{
    _tenantService = tenantService;
}
```

The problem is that the `TenantService` instance resolved inside the `AggregateCommandHandlerBase` is different to the one resolved inside the `SubmitSubmissionJob`, despite all of this code running on the same thread.

[image]

We bind the `TenantService` in NinjectWebCommon this way:

```
kernel.Bind<ITenantService>().To<TenantService>().InScope(x =>
{
   return (HttpContext.Current != null ? (object)HttpContext.Current : (object)Thread.CurrentThread);
});
```

but we also tried this:

```
kernel.Bind<ITenantService>().To<TenantService>().When(x => HttpContext.Current != null).InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<ITenantService>().To<TenantService>().When(x => HttpContext.Current == null).InThreadScope();
```

Both bindings result in the same behaviour - the `TenantService` resolved inside the code `AggregateCommandHandlerBase` is a different instance to the one resolved inside the job, which causes the tenant data to not be passed further down the line.

We've been spinning our wheels on this for hours and can't figure out why the instances are different. Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As long as you are using async methods (with awaits) there is no reason that the processing will be held on the same thread before and after awaits.
This may help : https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/issues/222